# Accessing nested element by index array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have two arrays

- `dataArr` - An array containing an unknown number of arrays and objects that may contain an unknown number of arrays and objects and so on. The array may also contain properties at various levels (think nested JSON)
- `indexArr` - An array of length `n` containing the keys to access a specific item in `dataArr`

How would I go about retrieving, adding and updating values in `dataArr[indexArr[0]][indexArr[1]][indexArr[2]]...[indexArr[n]]` without creating a new array?

Languages of interest: `javascript` and `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Create recursive function that you pass in indexes array and origin array.

```
function getItem(data, indexes) {
    if (indexes.length) {
        var index = indexes.shift();

        // if index exist - dive deeper, else return indicator that failed.
        if (typeof data[index] !== 'undefined') {
            return getItem(data[index], indexes);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // will be returned when no more indexes passed - last element reached
    return data;
}

getItems(dataArr, [1, 5, 9, 'a', 'sum', 99]);
```